# Recyclerview Doesn't Load Methods when element not show in screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

When I use recyclerview if I do not scroll the page the methods of the elements not shown are not loaded, and with that when I use the elements on the other screen some values ​​come set with the default value of the model. I need the methods to be loaded even if the element is not being viewed, so I can retrieve the information on the next screen.

Comment: Do you use notifyDataSetChanged when you filled RecyclerView?

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish is contrary to what a RecyclerView does. In a RecyclerView you are actually recycling the views in screen and replacing the data. 

What you need to do, is refresh the item view info everytime the view shows on screen using a View Holder in a RecyclerView Adapter. Are you already doing that? because I'm not sure I understand what kind of methods do you need to execute if it isn't on screen for the user to interact with that view.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help, 
Answering your questions, I use RecyclerView to add items to a shopping cart type, when the process was manual item by item there were no issues as the item was always displayed on the save screen, but when implemented add function several items in this cart a single time, problems arose with this question, because there is a discount calculation and quantity of items, and exactly this field that when the object is saved it comes as 0.00 if in the save screen I do not scroll manually screen.
I'm using Kotlin and use notifyChange () whenever changes occur.

Comment: Sorry in ActivityViewModel i use notifyObservers()